# WebAPI Help Page - Error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I followed the tutorial on ASP.Net website to add Help Pages on a WebAPI empty project. (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)

The thing is that I indeed access the help page index but when I click on a end point link to get details and samples it gives me a 404 error.

Here is the screen shot:
[image: 404 Error]

I don't know why it doesn't work, I have currently a Model, and a controller with Entity Framework.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Swaggger instead for help pages. It's better than the WebAPI Help.
Just download this package through NuGet:

```
<package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but nevertheless resolved a similar problem for me. For anyone else who has installed Swagger, once you install if you navigate to /swagger on your site's URL it will show you Web API docs. Swagger is definitely better then the default help page :)

Answer (score 0):

In the Global.asax file, add the following code to the Application_Start method, if it is not there already:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Add this code, if not present.
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // ...
}
```

to register areas.